# h264 codec in VLC 2.0.5

Tags: vlc

It seems the latest VLC (2.0.5; 32-bit and 64-bit versions) can not do h264 compression (though VP8 and WMV2 work fine).  The resulting file is almost empty though there are no errors.  Is this a known bug or does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?  I put one debug output below but it's too cryptic for me to understand.

```
qt4 debug: MRL passed to the Sout: file:///C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi
qt4 warning: Transcode MRL: sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='C:\Users\me\Videos\finaltest.mp4'}
qt4 debug: Adding option: file-caching=300
qt4 debug: Adding option: sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='C:\Users\me\Videos\finaltest.mp4'}
main debug: adding item `Streaming' ( file:///C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi )
qt4 debug: Adding a new MRL to recent ones: file:///C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi
main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
main debug: rebuild done - 2 items, index 0
main debug: processing request item: Streaming, node: Playlist, skip: 0
main debug: resyncing on Streaming
main debug: Streaming is at 1
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on Streaming
main debug: Streaming is at 1
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'Streaming'
main debug: using sout chain=`transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='C:\Users\me\Videos\finaltest.mp4'}'
main debug: stream=`std'
main debug: looking for sout stream module: 1 candidate
main debug: set config option: sout-standard-access to file
main debug: set config option: sout-standard-mux to mp4
main debug: set config option: sout-standard-dst to C:\Users\me\Videos\finaltest.mp4
main debug: looking for sout access module: 1 candidate
access_output_file debug: file access output opened (C:\Users\me\Videos\finaltest.mp4)
main debug: using sout access module "access_output_file"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 2.413 ms - Total 2.413 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 2.413 ms)
main debug: looking for sout mux module: 1 candidate
mux_mp4 debug: Mp4 muxer opened
main debug: using sout mux module "mux_mp4"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.131 ms - Total 1.131 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.131 ms)
stream_out_standard debug: using `file/mp4://C:\Users\me\Videos\finaltest.mp4'
main debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_standard"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 5.368 ms - Total 5.368 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 5.368 ms)
main debug: stream=`transcode'
main debug: looking for sout stream module: 1 candidate
main debug: set config option: sout-transcode-vcodec to h264
main debug: set config option: sout-transcode-vb to 0
main debug: set config option: sout-transcode-scale to 0
main debug: set config option: sout-transcode-acodec to mp3
main debug: set config option: sout-transcode-ab to 128
main debug: set config option: sout-transcode-channels to 2
main debug: set config option: sout-transcode-samplerate to 44100
stream_out_transcode debug: codec audio=mp3  44100Hz 2 channels 128Kb/s
stream_out_transcode debug: codec video=h264 0x0 scaling: 0.000000 0kb/s
main debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_transcode"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 4.629 ms - Total 4.629 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.629 ms)
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `file:///C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi' gives access `file' demux `' path `/C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi'
main debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='' location='/C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi' file='C:\Users\me\Videos\vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi'
main debug: looking for access_demux module: 3 candidates
main debug: no access_demux module matching "file" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.496 ms - Total 0.496 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.496 ms)
main debug: creating access 'file' location='/C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi', path='C:\Users\me\Videos\vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi'
main debug: looking for access module: 3 candidates
filesystem debug: opening file `C:\Users\me\Videos\vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi'
main debug: using access module "filesystem"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.432 ms - Total 0.432 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.432 ms)
main debug: Using stream method for AStream*
main debug: starting pre-buffering
main debug: received first data after 0 ms
main debug: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 16393 KiB/s
main debug: looking for stream_filter module: 4 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.161 ms - Total 0.161 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.161 ms)
main debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
main debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.133 ms - Total 0.133 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.133 ms)
main debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='' location='/C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi' file='C:\Users\me\Videos\vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi'
main debug: looking for demux module: 55 candidates
avi debug: 
avi debug: 
avi debug: 
avi debug: 
avi debug: 
avi debug: 
avi debug: 
avi debug: skipping movi chunk
avi debug: 
avi debug: * LIST-root size:142188528 pos:0
avi debug:      + RIFF-AVI  size:142188520 pos:0
avi debug:      |    + LIST-hdrl size:10208 pos:12
avi debug:      |    |    + avih size:56 pos:24
avi debug:      |    |    + LIST-strl size:116 pos:88
avi debug:      |    |    |    + strh size:56 pos:100
avi debug:      |    |    |    + strf size:40 pos:164
avi debug:      |    |    + LIST-strl size:94 pos:212
avi debug:      |    |    |    + strh size:56 pos:224
avi debug:      |    |    |    + strf size:18 pos:288
avi debug:      |    |    + JUNK size:9906 pos:314
avi debug:      |    + LIST-movi size:142176764 pos:10228
avi debug:      |    + idx1 size:1520 pos:142187000
avi debug: AVIH: 2 stream, flags  HAS_INDEX IS_INTERLEAVED TRUST_CKTYPE 
avi debug: stream[0] rate:4997 scale:1000 samplesize:0
avi debug: stream[0] video(YUY2) 1920x1080 24bpp 4.997000fps
main debug: selecting program id=0
avi debug: stream[1] rate:176372 scale:4 samplesize:4
avi debug: stream[1] audio(0x1 - ) 2 channels 44100Hz 16bits
main debug: Creating an input for 'Streaming'
avi debug: selected standard index for stream[0]
avi debug: selected standard index for stream[1]
avi debug: stream[0] created 34 index entries
avi debug: stream[1] created 61 index entries
avi debug: stream[0] length:6 (based on index)
avi debug: stream[1] length:6 (based on index)
main debug: using demux module "avi"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 2.590 ms - Total 2.590 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 2.590 ms)
main debug: looking for a subtitle file in C:\Users\me\Videos\
main debug: looking for packetizer module: 21 candidates
main debug: using packetizer module "rawvideo"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.643 ms - Total 0.643 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.643 ms)
main debug: looking for packetizer module: 21 candidates
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
main debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_copy"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 5.806 ms - Total 5.806 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 5.806 ms)
main debug: starting in sync mode
main debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader\filename.luac
main debug: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
main debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 2.885 ms - Total 2.885 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 2.885 ms)
main debug: `file:///C:/Users/me/Videos/vlc-record-2013-04-07-11h41m28s-dshow___-.avi' successfully opened
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: switching to async mode
main debug: adding a new sout input (sout_input:000000000399d820)
stream_out_transcode debug: creating video transcoding from fcc=`YUY2' to fcc=`h264'
main debug: Buffering 8%
main debug: looking for decoder module: 32 candidates
main debug: using decoder module "rawvideo"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 4.216 ms - Total 4.216 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.216 ms)
main debug: looking for encoder module: 13 candidates
x264 debug: version x264 0.129.X
main debug: adding a new sout input (sout_input:00000000039f4610)
main debug: Buffering 16%
main debug: Buffering 25%
main debug: Buffering 33%
main debug: Buffering 41%
main debug: Buffering 50%
main debug: Buffering 58%
main debug: Buffering 66%
main debug: using encoder module "x264"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 9.890 ms - Total 9.890 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 9.890 ms)
main debug: removing module "x264"
x264 debug: framecount still in libx264 buffer: 0
main debug: Buffering 75%
main debug: Buffering 83%
main debug: Buffering 91%
main debug: Buffering 100%
main debug: Stream buffering done (325 ms in 27 ms)
stream_out_transcode debug: creating audio transcoding from fcc=`s16l' to fcc=`mp3 '
main debug: looking for decoder module: 32 candidates
araw debug: samplerate:44100Hz channels:2 bits/sample:16
main debug: using decoder module "araw"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.111 ms - Total 0.111 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.111 ms)
main debug: looking for encoder module: 13 candidates
avcodec debug: libavcodec initialized (interface 0x361e00)
avcodec debug: found encoder MPEG I/II Layer 3
main debug: using encoder module "avcodec"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 4.349 ms - Total 4.349 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.349 ms)
stream_out_transcode debug: Looking for filter (s16l->s32l, channels 2->2, rate 44100->44100)
main debug: looking for audio filter module: 13 candidates
audio_format debug: s16l->f32l, bits per sample: 16->32
main debug: using audio filter module "audio_format"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.094 ms - Total 0.094 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.094 ms)
main debug: Filter 'audio_format' (0000000003952fc8) appended to chain
main debug: looking for audio filter module: 13 candidates
audio_format debug: f32l->s32l, bits per sample: 32->32
main debug: using audio filter module "audio_format"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.062 ms - Total 0.062 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.062 ms)
main debug: Filter 'audio_format' (0000000003954c38) appended to chain
stream_out_transcode debug: Got complete audio filter chain
main debug: adding a new input
mux_mp4 debug: adding input
main debug: Decoder buffering done in 5 ms
stream_out_transcode debug: decoder aspect is 1.777778:1
stream_out_transcode debug: source pixel aspect is 1.000000:1
stream_out_transcode debug: scaled pixel aspect is 1.000000:1
stream_out_transcode debug: source 1920x1080, destination 1920x1080
stream_out_transcode debug: encoder aspect is 1920:1080
main debug: looking for video filter2 module: 18 candidates
swscale debug: 1920x1080 chroma: YUY2 -> 1920x1080 chroma: I420 with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
main debug: using video filter2 module "swscale"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.038 ms - Total 1.038 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.038 ms)
main debug: Filter 'Swscale' (00000000039537e8) appended to chain
stream_out_transcode debug: destination (after video filters) 1920x1080
main debug: looking for encoder module: 13 candidates
x264 debug: version x264 0.129.X
main debug: using encoder module "x264"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 6.441 ms - Total 6.441 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 6.441 ms)
main debug: adding a new input
mux_mp4 debug: adding input
avi warning: cannot get packet header, track disabled
main debug: EOF reached
main debug: waiting decoder fifos to empty
main debug: finished input
main debug: removing module "rawvideo"
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `YUY2', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: removing a sout input (sout_input:000000000399d820)
main debug: TIMER encoding video frame : 416.026 ms - Total 531.820 ms / 35 intvls (Avg 15.195 ms)
main debug: removing module "rawvideo"
main debug: removing module "x264"
x264 debug: framecount still in libx264 buffer: 34
main debug: Filter 00000000039537e8 removed from chain
main debug: removing module "swscale"
mux_mp4 debug: removing input
main debug: removing module "packetizer_copy"
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `s16l', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: removing a sout input (sout_input:00000000039f4610)
main debug: TIMER encoding audio frame : 0.000 ms - Total 330.062 ms / 537 intvls (Avg 0.615 ms)
main debug: removing module "araw"
main debug: removing module "avcodec"
main debug: Filter 0000000003952fc8 removed from chain
main debug: removing module "audio_format"
main debug: Filter 0000000003954c38 removed from chain
main debug: removing module "audio_format"
mux_mp4 debug: removing input
main warning: no more input streams for this mux
main debug: removing module "avi"
main debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
main debug: removing module "filesystem"
main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
main debug: dead input
main debug: destroying useless sout
main debug: destroying chain... (name=transcode)
main debug: removing module "stream_out_transcode"
main debug: destroying chain done
main debug: destroying chain... (name=std)
main debug: removing module "stream_out_standard"
main debug: removing module "mux_mp4"
mux_mp4 debug: Close
mux_mp4 debug: movie duration 0s
mux_mp4 debug: created 0 chunks (stco)
mux_mp4 debug: created 0 chunks (stco)
main debug: removing module "access_output_file"
access_output_file debug: file access output closed
main debug: destroying chain done
main debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: TIMER input launching for 'Streaming' : 36.462 ms - Total 36.462 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 36.462 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install this codec pack :)

http://www.vlccodec.com/

hope it works after that !